# mat-form-field overlapping into button below

Tags: angular, overlapping, mat-form-field

i have a problem with a mat-form-field overlapping into a button. Making it so only the lower half is clickable.

I have the app hosted here on AWS https://main.d225v44fsxss8s.amplifyapp.com/selector

The problem is with the query button on the bottom left. It is being overlapped by the T_positions form field.

[image]

I have modified the form field sizes a bit but the issue still happens if i have all of those values to default.

I have tried adjusting the z-index of the button but that hasnt worked.

Edit:
I also have another problem. That one is with the little info boxes.
Ideally i would want them to be sizes in such a way that their width is equal to the largest sentence they contain.

or alternatively that they always stretch from their position to the right of the screen.

but i havent managed to get either working so far.
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer in the angular discord.

Here is a quick stackblitz reproducing the issue.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-form-field-overlap?file=src/app/autocomplete-display-example.css

The problem was that i had

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field {
    margin-bottom: -1.25em
}
```

to remove the gap between the input field and my button because it was simply wasted space.

The proper way to do this however is

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-wrapper {
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

(The setting is commented out in the stackblitz so anyone can confirm that it works)
which removes that space but also does not overlap.